# Creating matrix with probabilities depending on index column

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

How do I create a matrix 10x10, with only 1's (heads), and 0's (tails), with the probability of a heads is 1 divided by the index of the column.

I tried several things but it won't work which is really frustrating. I tried to do it with a vector and a for loop.

```
  mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/h, 1-(1/h)), 10))
```

But now the only question is how to define h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `sapply`

```
n_col <- 10
n_row <- 10
mat <- matrix(nrow = n_row,
              ncol = n_col)

set.seed(1)
sapply(1:n_col, function(x) {
  mat[, x] <- sample(x = c(1, 0),
                     size = n_row,
                     replace = TRUE,
                     prob = c(1/x, 1 - 1/x))
})
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
# [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
# [3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [4,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [5,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
# [7,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [9,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[10,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you mistunderstood me a bit. I need to have a matrix with only zeros and ones. The probability of a 1 is equal to 1/indexcolumn (so in the first column only 1's).

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for pointing this out. Will delete my answer and come back if I have a solution. Regards.

Comment: @Max, I saw your other question. Updated the answer such that you can generate `n` coin flips by changing `n_row` to whatever number you desire. Best

Comment: A big thanks for the help. But now I want to make a 100x10 matrix with the same function, it's a bit frustrating since it gives only NA values.

Comment: See my previous comment.